# One mapping to toggle NERDTree and open to current file when toggling on

Tags: vim, nerdtree

I'm trying to find a way to have a normal mode mapping that can toggle NERDTree, but when toggling on, tell NERDTree to find the current file.

I know about `NERDTreeToggle` and `NERDTreeFind`, and what I'm looking to do is essentially a combination of those two commands.

Here's my use case:

1. When NERDTree is not open, I can hit `<C-\>` and NERDTree will open to the current file.
2. I can then hit `<C-\>` again and NERDTree will close.

Answer (score 12):

The first answer didn't work for me so I came up with this:

```
function MyNerdToggle()
    if &filetype == 'nerdtree'
        :NERDTreeToggle
    else
        :NERDTreeFind
    endif
endfunction

nnoremap <C-\> :call MyNerdToggle()<CR>
```

Comment: It's not perfect. The mapping has to be used twice when not on NERDTree buffer and want to close it.

Comment: I agree. However this works ideally for me when I combine with g:NERDTreeQuitOnOpen=1.

Comment: It's a good point. In that case it solves situations where you want to open one file at a time. I think we need patch or plugin for NERDTree itself to provide an option that would auto-find whenever NERDTree buffer gets reopened.

Answer (score 7):

This will do exactly what you want:

```
nnoremap <silent> <expr> <C-\> g:NERDTree.IsOpen() ? "\:NERDTreeClose<CR>" : bufexists(expand('%')) ? "\:NERDTreeFind<CR>" : "\:NERDTree<CR>"
```

Comment: In neovim v0.6 I had to quote the first expression as well (`"g:NERDTree.IsOpen()"`)

Answer (score 2):

```
function! NerdTreeToggleFind()
    if exists("g:NERDTree") && g:NERDTree.IsOpen()
        NERDTreeClose
    elseif filereadable(expand('%'))
        NERDTreeFind
    else
        NERDTree
    endif
endfunction

nnoremap <C-\> :call NerdTreeToggleFind()<CR>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is the `:NERDTreeToggle` command, which you actually need, and just add `%`

```
nnoremap <C-\> :NERDTreeToggle %<CR>
```

In the help provided to the NERD tree you can find that [`:NERDTree`](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree/blob/master/doc/NERD_tree.txt#L104-L110) command depends on the argument given, and that in the case of [`:NERDTreeToggle`](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree/blob/master/doc/NERD_tree.txt#L117-L120) if no NERD tree exists for this tab then this command acts the same as the [`:NERDTree`](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree/blob/master/doc/NERD_tree.txt#L104-L110) command.

Comment: Not really... it seems to open a directory, not a file... besides, it doesn't work at all if the NERDTree buffor is already initiated but closed (invisible).

Answer (score 1):

After Lewis R's answer and realizing it did not work for me, I've tweaked it a little bit and came up with this

```
" map nerdtree to the ctrl+n
function MyNerdToggle()
    if &filetype == 'nerdtree' || exists("g:NERDTree") && g:NERDTree.IsOpen()
        :NERDTreeToggle
    else
        :NERDTreeFind
    endif
endfunction

nnoremap <C-\> :call MyNerdToggle()<CR>
```